# Fix for ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping property error on @Qualifier with the same method type

Tags: java, mapstruct

I'm getting ambiguous mapping error by "[mapping from map](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-mapping-from-map/src/main/java/org/mapstruct/example/mapper/util/MappingUtil.java)" using MapStruct 1.3.1.Final

```
@Mapper( uses = MappingUtil.class )
public interface SourceTargetMapper {

    SourceTargetMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( SourceTargetMapper.class );

    @Mapping(source = "map", target = "aProperty", qualifiedBy = A.class )
    @Mapping(source = "map", target = "bProperty", qualifiedBy = B.class )
    Target toTarget(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> map);
}


public class MappingUtil {

  @Qualifier
  @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
  public @interface A {
  }

  @Qualifier
  @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
  public @interface B {
  }

  @A
  public String abc(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> in) {
     return (String) in.get("first_key").get("a_second_key");
  }

  @B
  public String xyz(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> in) {
     return (String) in.get("first_key").get("b_second_key");
  }

}
```

When I change Either @A or @B to a different type, the error goes away

```
  @B
  public int xyz(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> in) {
     return (int) in.get("first_key").get("b_second_key");
  }
```

What am I missing? The [docs example](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.3/reference/html/) used two methods of the same type so it should not be an issue

EDIT: Same issue on Mapstruct 4.1.2.Final

Comment: Have you tried 1.4.2.Final?

Comment: Just tried it, same issue

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of qualifiers is not correct. Here is the [link](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/1.3/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) which shows how to implement custom mapping with qualifiers in case of ambiguous mappings.

Below is the short version of code of how you can create custom mappings based on qualifiers:

```
@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface Translator {
}

@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface A {
}

@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface B {
}

@Translator
public class MappingUtil {
    @A
    public String abc(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> in) {
        return (String) in.get("first_key").get("a_second_key");
    }

    @B
    public String xyz(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> in) {
        return (String) in.get("first_key").get("b_second_key");
    }
}

@Mapper( uses = MappingUtil.class )
public interface SourceTargetMapper {

    SourceTargetMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( SourceTargetMapper.class );

    @Mapping(source = "map", target = "aProperty", qualifiedBy = { Translator.class, A.class } )
    @Mapping(source = "map", target = "bProperty", qualifiedBy = { Translator.class, B.class } )
    Target toTarget(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> map);
}
```

**Alternative:**

You can use `qualifiedByName` if you do not want to create separate Utility class. Below is the example code for it:

```
@Mapper
public interface SourceTargetMapper {

    SourceTargetMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( SourceTargetMapper.class );

    @Mapping(source = "map", target = "aProperty", qualifiedByName= "abc" )
    @Mapping(source = "map", target = "bProperty", qualifiedByName= "xyz" )
    Target toTarget(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> map);

    @Named("abc")
    default String abc(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> in) {
        // return whatever need to return
    }

    @Named("xyz")
    default String xyz(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> in) {
        // return whatever need to return
    }
}
```

Comment: This alternative works! Would be still keen to know the root cause of the posted issue though

Comment: Interesting, I think that the example in the question should work. @helpme can you please raise and issue in the mapstruct project so we can have a look at this?

Comment: @Filip There must be some importance of `Translator` class right? Though I will give it a try to both the above scenarios on my side.

Comment: That's multi level qualifiers. One on top of the class and another on the method, but it should work without it as well, basically it should be identical to the `@Named`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work correctly when using 1.4.2.Final. However, in 1.5.0.Beta1 this is no longer working due to the newly introduced Map to Bean mapping. We are investigating how we can fix this.

However, there is an alternative solution that would make this work properly:

```
@Mapper( uses = MappingUtil.class )
public interface SourceTargetMapper {

    SourceTargetMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper( SourceTargetMapper.class );

    @Mapping(source = "first_property", target = "aProperty", qualifiedBy = A.class )
    @Mapping(source = "first_property", target = "bProperty", qualifiedBy = B.class )
    Target toTarget(Map<String,Map<String, Object>> map);
}


public class MappingUtil {

  @Qualifier
  @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
  public @interface A {
  }

  @Qualifier
  @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
  public @interface B {
  }

  @A
  public String abc(Map<String, Object> in) {
     return (String) in.get("a_second_key");
  }

  @B
  public String xyz(Map<String, Object> in) {
     return (String) in.get("b_second_key");
  }

}
```

Note the change of the signatures in the `MappingUtil` and the change in `Mapping#source`.